# c programming - printing sentences

Tags: c

this is my first time using this site as well as learning c programming. 
I'm trying to write a code which lets a user type in a sentence and the code prints it back out.

My attempt:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char array[1000];
    printf("Please enter a phrase: ");
    int index = 0;
    while(array[index]!= '\0')
    {
        scanf("%c",&array[index]);
        ++index;
    }
    index = 0;
    while(array[index]!= '\n')
    {
        printf("%c",array[index]);
        ++index;
    }
}
```

I can't find the reason to why this code does not work.

Comment: What's your input, what's the output, and what's your expected output?

Comment: Walk through it in your head (or on paper) - how does that first while loop ever exit?

Comment: BTW, `array` is _uninitialized_.

Comment: @tim is you question answered and works my code for you? Or do you need more help?

Comment: Thanks you john, I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can get expected output using your concept also.. Try something using following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char array[1000];
printf("Please enter a phrase: ");
int index =0;
    scanf("%c",&array[index]);
while(array[index]!='\n')
{
    scanf("%c",&array[++index]);
}
index=0;
while(array[index]!= '\n')
{
    printf("%c",array[index]);
    ++index;
}

printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anbu, I've already figured it out and it is very similar to yours.

Comment: This approach fails if `EOF` occurs before `'\n'` --> endless loop.  Checking the result of `scanf()` is a good idea to detect EOF.  Using `fgets()` is even better.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first and foremost you'll need to initialize all your array. If you don't, the user input will print along with lots of meaningless garbage.

Secondly, the test portion of your first while loop checks for a null character which will never exist because "array[]" is just a simple character array (not a string) therefore, a call to scanf() doesn't insert the null character at the end. This causes an infinite loop.

Thirdly, your first while loop should be a do-while so that you first read a character, then test the character, otherwise if the "index" variable increments first...

Lastly, I posted the code that i used to get it to run using the method that you chose. However, as an alternative to the method you chose, the c standard library has the gets() function, which will allow you to read an entire line of input and return the string entered (actually it returns a pointer to the character array created but i think you catch my drift), and the puts() function which prints a string pointed to by the pointer used as an argument.
For more info on this problem in general, including gets() and puts(), refer to "C Programming A Modern Approach" by K.N. King, Chapter 13: Strings.I hope this helps.

Happy Coding!! :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int index = 0;

   char array[1000];

    while(index < 1000){
        array[index] = '0';
        index++;
   }

    printf("Please enter a phrase: ");

    index = 0;

    do {
            scanf("%c", &array[index]);

        } while(array[index] != '\n' && index++ < 1000); 

    index = 0;

    while(index < 1000)
    printf("%c", array[index++]);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your looking for this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    char array[1000];
    printf("Please enter a phrase: ");

    scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", array);

    printf("\n%s", array);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks it did work but there were few things that I couldn't recognize from your code (such as %[^\n]%*c), but I was able to figure it out.

Comment: `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", array);` saves nothing in `array` if the user inputs only `'\n'`, then `printf("\n%s", array);` is UB.  Add `array[0] = 0;` before the `scanf("%999[^\n]%*c")` call, or check `scanf()` result or better yet: use `fgets()`.

Comment: @tim nice :D have a good day! BTW you can accept and upvote answer's how helped you, so that other people with the same problem find the answer faster! (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)